# Html text box variable to PHP then to shell bash to find file by name

Tags: php, html, bash, shell

I want to include a text box on my website that will search my linux box for any files with the typed text in it.

When I "submit", the text box outputs...    "www.website.com/file_finder.php?name=samba"..
Next, "file_finder.PHP" file is called...
The PHP file is supposed to enter "./file_finder smaba" into the linux box to run "file_finder"....

Manually entering "./file_finder samba" at the CLI works just fine. It finds files with "samba" in it.

However, clicking submit on the text DOES NOT output a search based on what was typed. IT outputs based on the last time "file_finder" was run at the command line manually????

1. enter "./file_finder fstab"
2. bash outputs all files with "fstab" in them
3. goto to website enter "samba" in the text box and hit submit
4. php echo statement #1 outputs "samba"
5. php echo statement #2 outputs "./file_finder samba"
6. the website outputs a list of files with "fstab" instead?!?!?

Ideas why it's not working??

file_finder.php:

```
      <?php
       echo $_GET['name']."<br>";
        $nname=$_GET['name'];

        $shline = "./file_finder " .$nname."";
        echo $shline;
        $output = shell_exec($shline); 
        echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
        ?>
```

file_finder:

```
#!/bin/bash
 find -L /var/www/htdocs/ -type f -iname "*"$1"*" -exec basename {} \; > /var/www/htdocs/flr_logs/finder_list.log

  sort -k +1 /var/www/htdocs/flr_logs/finder_list.log >> /var/www/htdocs/flr_logs/finder_sorted.log

   cat /var/www/htdocs/flr_logs/finder_sorted.log
```

Comment: `$nname=escapeshellarg($_GET['name']);`  // VERY IMPORTANT

Comment: `"*"$1"*"` should be `"*$1*"`  Equally important

Answer (score 0):

see ny warning about shell injection in the comments,

> However, clicking submit on the text DOES NOT output a search based on
>   what was typed. IT outputs based on the last time "file_finder" was
>   run at the command line manually????

The scriot needs write permission to the file `/var/www/htdocs/flr_logs/finder_list.log` etc...

But really the script should be using a unique temporary filename so that two online users can use it at the same time...

Or better rwrite the script to use a pipeline instead:

**file_finder:**

```
#!/bin/bash
find -L /var/www/htdocs/ -iname "*$1*" -type f -printf '%f\n' |
  sort -k +1
```

note, I fixed the shell injection above and substituded -printf which is more efficient than exec, also reordered the tests so that the cheaper iname test runs first.